# How to keep one highly-correlated variable from swamping the rest in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk, sklearn-pandas

I'm building a classifier to detect when Donald Trump is tweeting from @realDonaldTrump, instead of a staffer. It uses tweets from 2016 to train the model, using the tweeting device to infer the authorship — if the message was sent from an Android phone, it's Trump; otherwise, it's a staffer.

Right now, I'm using a Python sklearn `BernoulliNB` classifier that uses two sets of features. The first is a bag-of-words vector of the president's tweet text. The second is a simple binary variable — does the tweet have a link or not?

I'm using `pandas` to handle the data and `sklearn_pandas` to make combining the features easier. Here's a snippet of the dataframe:

```
                                                  text  year   type   link
0    RT @realDonaldTrump: Happy Birthday @DonaldJTr...  2016  staff   true
1    Happy Birthday @DonaldJTrumpJr!\nhttps://t.co/...  2016  staff   true
2    Happy New Year to all, including to my many en...  2016  trump  false
3    Russians are playing @CNN and @NBCNews for suc...  2016  trump  false
4    Join @AmerIcan32, founded by Hall of Fame lege...  2016  staff   true
```

Here's a simplified sample of my code:

```
# Grab tweets, which have 'text', 'link' and 'type' columns
train_tweets = pd.read_json("data/condensed_2016.json")

vectorizer = DataFrameMapper([
('link', MultiLabelBinarizer()),
('text', CountVectorizer(
    analyzer = 'word', 
    tokenizer = None, 
    preprocessor = None, 
    stop_words = 'english', 
    max_features = 500) )
])

# Build vector of features from training set
train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_tweets)

classify = BernoulliNB()
classify = classify.fit( train_data_features, train_tweets['type'] )
```

The only problem is that the `link` column is *extremely* highly correlated with staffer authorship — Trump almost never includes a link of any kind in his tweets. So whenever I classify a tweet that contains a link and check the probabilities with `classify.predict_proba()`, I get an insane level of specificity — like a 99.999 percent chance a staffer wrote the tweet.

That essentially makes the bag-of-words analysis moot. I guess it's not a *bad* thing, but it makes the algorithm more brittle. Is there an obvious thing I can do to address this?

Comment: ohh, nice idea! do you have the data somewhere? I'd like to give it a try!

Comment: this fella is collecting them hourly: https://github.com/bpb27/trump_tweet_data_archive

Comment: sweet! for your problem, I would clean the tweet data first to remove all links, RT, mentions, etc. I would also remove the `link` column if its that correlated.

Comment: in my actual code I do a fair amount of custom cleaning and exclusion at the token level... but is removing a highly-correlated column considered best practice?

Comment: not always. but in this particular case when you are only interested in the tweet text, the link column just seems to be adding leakage to your model.

Answer (score 2):

You could try Random Under or Over sampling which will balance the distribution of your data. Over sampling can produce Memory Errors however. Having tried under sampling it can produce poor results depending on your data, so I'd say just try both out.

RandomOverSampler: http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.html#imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler

RandomUnderSampler: http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html#imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler

Or you can use a combination of the under and over sampling: http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.combine.SMOTETomek.html#imblearn.combine.SMOTETomek